# Azure Boards extension for comment like tree

Tags: azure-devops, azure-boards

my user very unhappy comment in azure boards
it is difficult to track the hierarchy of comment's messages, you have to copy the previous message in manual mode.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

We have helped you to submit the relevant [suggestion ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/1121148/azure-boards-for-comment-like-tree.html). To receive the notification about it in time, you can vote and follow this suggestion ticket.

In addition, If you have more suggestions, you can also add a comment in this suggestion ticket to add a detailed description.